# Adding Tables to the AspNetSqlProvider Database Tables (Membership, Roles, and Profile)

Tags: .net, sql-server, membership, roles

I'm building an asp.net website and I would like to use the membership provider for SQLServer. I've installed the tables in my own custom database and everything works great. My question is, if I'm going to build this site using these tables for security, do I integrate my database design with the design supplied by Microsoft, or do I create my own database and use two different databases with my web app?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either create a distinct membership database, or you can **[integrate SQLMembershipProvider into your existing business database](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/security/Video/cc178919)**.

The choice depends on your architecture constraints. For example, if you want to centralize and share your membership data with other applications, it's cleaner to use a dedicated membership database.

Answer (score 1):

You only use one database. Just run [Aspnet_regsql.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x28wfk74.aspx) on it to create the tables and procedures.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I understand that, but what about my tables? Do I just add them to the database that I installed the membership tables using aspnet_regsql?

Comment: Yes. You just add them to that database.